# Why are Lunar White LEDs not a standard part, or what am I missing?

Tags: led, specifications, color

TL;DR: Lunar White is a widely-used standard color in signaling work (like, every pedestrian signal that conforms to ITE specifications uses it, as far as I can tell), so why can't you buy Lunar White LEDs as COTS save for a few non-ANSI white bins that just happen to fall into the definition's color space?

I've been looking for Lunar White LEDs, using the chromaticity definitions for Lunar White from [NBS Handbook 95](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/hb/nbshandbook95.pdf) as the other places it's specified are major $$$ documents, for a signaling application and have been able to find only a very select few COTS parts that meet that definition (some 3-step MacAdam ellipse bins at 5000K as well as the Cree EasyWhite 2-step bin at 4000K seem to work out even taking binning tolerances into account, but none of the ANSI white bins do).

Why is this? Have the two principal users of Lunar White lights (AREMA for railway use in the US, and ITE for pedestrian signals as that's the quoted color for the WALK signal) changed their definitions from the old NBS Lunar White of x>=0.325 and y between 0.170+0.5x and 0.195+0.5x on a CIE plot? (The NBS also set an upper limit on x, but it's complex and not really relevant to the discussion as LEDs can generate a far blue-er white than incandescents ever could.)  Or do vendors of LED traffic and railway signals order their LEDs custom-binned to meet the appropriate (NBS, AREMA, or ITE) specification for Lunar White?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with different LED pigments requiring different chemistries. You can make "white" LEDs out of yellow ones or out of blue ones, different chemistries, different forward voltage and so on. I don't know the technical details, but I would imagine that a pigment that might require a more costly procedure will not become a "high runner". In most products the exact nuance of white probably doesn't matter. With the exception of indoors lighting, which does require one specific nuance - but perhaps not necessarily this lunar white one.

Answer (score 3):

The NBS Handbook is from 1964, prior to ubiquitous LEDs, never mind white ones.

ANSI 4000K up to 5700K (and perhaps beyond) is squarely inside ITE "White".

This is a graph of CIE space with the ITE "white" plotted against CREE's colour bins and ANSI bins 4000K (rightmost red), 4500K, 5000K, 5700K (leftmost)

[image]
From Page 11, 12 [Cree Easywhite XLAMP MTG2 datasheet](https://downloads.cree-led.com/files/ds/x/XLamp-MTG2.pdf), TIE white below, and ANSI values, below.

### ANSI Colour Temperatures

[image]

From [ANSI_NEMA_ANSLG C78.377-2008](https://u.dianyuan.com/upload/space/2011/09/20/1316531931-531796.pdf), table A1.

### ITE

The ITE "Pedestrian Traffic Control Signal Indicators -- Light Emitting Diode Signal Modules", 2010, says the colour is just "white", and specifies it as

> The standard colors for
> the LED pedestrian signal module shall be
> white for the "walking person"

which it defines as

| colour | value |
| --- | --- |
| Blue boundary | x = 0.280 |
| Green boundary | 0.280 ≤ x < 0.400 y = 0.0983 + 0.7917•x |
| Yellow boundary | x = 0.400 |
| Purple boundary | 0.280 ≤ x < 0.400 y = 0.0483 + 0.7917•x |

The points are given as:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.280 | 0.320 |
| 0.400 | 0.415 |
| 0.400 | 0.365 |
| 0.280 | 0.270 |

[Pedestrian Traffic Control Signal Indicators -- Light Emitting Diode Signal Modules](http://www.signalcontrol.com/tech_papers/dialight/ITE_PTCSI_LED_Ped_Signal_Modules_Spec_8-4-10.pdf)

### Arlington Virginia

A document from 2014 one US jurisdiction references the ITE "LED Performance Specifications of the Pedestrian Traffic Control Signal Indications (PTCSI)" Part 2, “Pedestrian Traffic Signal Modules”, and specifies "Lunar White" as:

[image]
From [Arlington Virginia Traffice Signal and Street Light Speciciation](https://arlingtonva.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2013/12/Traffic-Signal-and-Street-Light-Specifications.pdf), May 2014, p39

It further specifies that the white LEDs will be the "latest InGaN teqhnology".

### US National Bureau of Standards

[image]
From NBS Handbook 95, p5.

### Site Visit

In 1969 several enterprising engineers made site visits to determine "lunar white" accurately.  They describe it as various shades of grey.

[image]
Crew Observations, in [Apollo 11 Preliminary Science Report, NASA SP-214](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/as11psr.pdf), 1969, p35.

Comment: I was able to dig up a copy of the appropriate bits of the AREMA C&S manual and the bad news is that they *didn't* just give up and broaden their definition of acceptable "white" -- current AREMA lunar white has an x between 0.329 and 0.441, with a y between 0.51x+.17 and 0.51x+.186, and this is no less challenging than the old NBS definition I originally was working with, it seems (especially given that the tolerances on chromaticity measurements are in the 0.005-0.01 range, which means that your bins effectively "bloat", no?)

Comment: BTW: would you rather I edit this into my original question given that ITE white is now far broader than a true Lunar White ever could be, or ask a new question instead, given that binning tolerances are also at question here (something I didn't bring up in my initial question)?